# Conditional formatting of single.php based on previous page?

Tags: wordpress

Here's one that's been eating at me.

I've got a collection of 12 posts called "Products" that have been assigned categories, let's say "military", "trucking", "construction", and "railroad". A lot of them overlap, where Product 1 may be applicable to both Military and Trucking and Product 2 just Railroad, for example. Easy enough.

Here's where it gets fun. The Military page (which is using one template) is bringing in all of the products that have been assigned to the Military category and the same for Trucking (which is using a different template). Everything is all well and good, but when I click through to Product 1, I want it to retain the template of the page it had just been on.

So basically, how do I have formatting for single.php be generated based on which page they entered from? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is on page load have the page check for a cookie of the previous page ID. Check what the layout for that page ID was and serve that.

Put this in your `footer.php` file:

```
global $wp_query; // Get the global query object
$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID; // Set ID to variable

setcookie('last_id', $post_id, false, '/'); // Set cookie for subsequent requests
```

This will set a cookie after all of the code ran on the current page. It is essentially setting the cookie for the next page. You can then check in your code for the single template:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['last_id']){
    $id = intval($_COOKIE['last_id']);
    // Code for setting template
}
```

Comment: Well, WP sure didn't like that.  "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tcci/www/www/wp-content/themes/tcci/header.php:3) in /home/tcci/www/www/wp-content/themes/tcci/sidebar-cookie.php on line 4"

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wordpress tag that does this - wp_get_referer. I was just trying to figure this out myself, and found the answer at http://zoerooney.com/blog/tutorials/using-the-referring-page-in-wordpress/

```
// use the WordPress tag wp_get_referer to assign the referring URL to the variable $referer
$referer = wp_get_referer();

// check if the URL is a specific one
if ( $referer == "whatever-your-previous-page-url-is" ) {

// if it is, do something

} else {

// if it isn't, do something else

}
```